# How do I create a new row within an if-condition in SAS?

Tags: sas, insert, rows

What I have:

```
Number Cost Amount
52 98 1
108 50 3
922 12 1
```

What I want:

```
Number Cost 
52 98 
108 50 
109 50
110 50
922 12 1
```

My dataset has a variable Amount. If Amount is 2 for a certain row, I want to create a new row right beneath it with the same Cost and the Number equal to that of the row above + 1. If the Amount is 3, I want to create two new rows right beneath it, both with the same Cost and with the Numbers being Number from row above +1 and Number from row above +2, and so on.
My final step would be to delete the Amount column, which I can do with

```
data want (drop=Amount);
    set have;
```

I am having problems implementing this, my thoughts have been to use proc sql insert into but I am having trouble combining this with an if condition that runs through the amount variable.

Code to reproduce table:

```
proc sql;
   create table want
       (Number num, Cost num, Amount num);

insert into want
    values(52,98,1)
    values(108,50,3)
    values(922,12,1);
```

Comment: If amount (n) is negative should n rows with -cost be inserted ?

Comment: No, that's not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you:

```
proc sort data=want out=want_s nodupkey;
  by Number;
run;
data result;
  keep Number Cost;
  set want_s;
  do i=1 to Amount;
    output;
    Number=Number+1;
  end;
run;
```

You might need to take care that Number does not overlap with the next input row like below:

```
Number ; Amount
108 ; 10
110 ; 1
```

Comment: This solved the problem perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DO` loop to output the `AMOUNT` number of rows.  You can code the *index* variable of the loop to increment the `NUMBER`

Example (untested)

```
data want(keep=number cost);
  set have;
  do number = number to number + amount-1;
    output;
  end;
```

However, you may not need to perform this *expansion* of data in some cases.  Many SAS Procedures provide a **WEIGHT** or **FREQ** statement that allows a variable to perform that statistical or processing roles.